# the program bosh is currently not installed

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

After successfully running:

```
$ sudo gem install bosh_cli --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

I receive the message

> The program 'bosh' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: sudo apt install bosh

However, I verified that it is installed, using:

```
$ gem list bosh_cli
bosh_cli (1.3262.26.0)
```

If I install bosh using apt, then I am unable to execute the expected commands such as:

```
$ bosh target 192.168.50.4 lite
File not found 'target'
```

For reference, I'm using the instructions [here](http://dmunozfer.es/como-instalar-cloud-foundry-en-local-ubuntu/)

Any assistance you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: Bosh cli v1 will be deprecated soon. You should use BOSH cli v2 instead which is implemented in go: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-cli

Comment: You should also try `gem which bosh_cli` to see if and where it is installed.

Comment: What does `bosh -v` show? Maybe you have installed 2 boshes and 2nd version of it have other syntax.